# In JMeter java api how to set POST Form values in a PreProcessor sampler?

Tags: java, jmeter, http-post

In a PreProcessor I am writing I can successfully update GET query string via sampler.

However if I use the same approach with POST, while I can list the FORM fields via getArguments(), the value does not get set.

```
  Arguments arguments = sampler.getArguments();
  for (int i=0; i<arguments.getArgumentCount(); i++) {
      Argument argument = arguments.getArgument(i);
      if (argument.getName().equals("page_submission_id")) {
          String newVal = "8743718386872";                         
          argument.setValue(newVal);
          System.out.println("Setting arg["+argument.getName()+"] to["+newVal+"]");
      }
  }
  sampler.setArguments(arguments);  
  printArgs(arguments);
```

The output from this shows Arguments values are unchanged.

```
Setting arg[page_submission_id] to[8743718386872]
Arguments After
   ...
   Found arg[page_submission_id] is[XXXXXXXXXXXXX]
   ...
```

Having dug into the jmeter code a bit further, there is a "runningVersion" attribute of an Attribute object which (via isRunningVersion()) is set true.

I have tried a few ways to get round this:

- force runningVersion to false - then values are set but a GET message is sent
- create a new Arguments object and add new Argument entries to it with values - this does not change the values

Can anyone point out the official way to set POST FORM field values before they get sent?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this:

1. (initially) by cleaning up the Thread Pool, as my initial
   attempts had included a number of things like "Regular Expression
   Extractors" and "User defined variables".  Once those were removed
   the approach I was using successfully changed the argument values, and
2. (when deeper in to my setup the problem came back) by adding the creation of a new Argments object and inserting (in the same order) new Argument objects with the value set as I require.  Then setting the sampler to use that new Arguments object.

   ```
   Arguments newArgs = new Arguments();
   Arguments arguments = sampler.getArguments();

   for (int i=0; i<arguments.getArgumentCount(); i++) {            
       Argument argument = arguments.getArgument(i);
       HTTPArgument newArg = new HTTPArgument();

       newArg.setName(arguments.getName());                            
       if (arguments.getName().equals("field_to_replace")) {
           newArg.setValue("new value");
       }
       else {
           newArg.setValue(arguments.getValue());
       }
       newArgs.addArgument(newArg);
   }
   sampler.setArguments(newArgs);
   ```

My take is that this down to the "if (isRunningVersion())" test within [setProperty()](http://www.jexamples.com/srchRes/org.apache.jmeter.testelement.AbstractTestElement.isRunningVersion) used by "Argument.setValue()" which I'm tripping over.

While this appears to work (for my test cases so far) I appreciate that overriding this may not be the correct formal approach.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you assigning a new value to an argument, but I fail to see where you updating sampler's arguments with the argument having the new value.

I'm a strong believer of [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) principle so instead of adding some more lines I would recommend simplifying your script as follows:

```
import org.apache.jmeter.config.Argument;

sampler.getArguments().removeArgument("page_submission_id");
sampler.addArgument("page_submission_id","8743718386872");
```

Also I hope you're using [JSR223 PreProcessor and Groovy language](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance).

Comment: Dimitri hi,  This is in Java, rather than Groovy, I figured i) the Argument I get is a reference to the object still in the Arguments list so I can update it directly and ii) (for good measure) the line "sampler.setArguments(arguments);" does the reinserting back into sampler - this works for GETs.  The other thing (which I didn't state) is that (in my case) there are two other requirements - 1) order of POST fields is important 2) the same named field (hidden) is used several times - removeArgument would remove all items with same name and then addArgument would add to the bottom of the list.